# Compute all element in integer list

Tags: perl

let's say you have set of integer in the list.

#### List Declare:

```
@lists = (22, 10, 5, 2);
```

but if I do want all the elements to be divide in let's say 2, is there anyways to do other than manually computing in running loop?

#### Don't want to compute like this:

```
foreach $list (@lists)
{
    print (list/2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@lists = [22, 10, 5, 2];
```

should be

```
@lists = (22, 10, 5, 2);
```

then you can

```
@lists = map { $_ / 2 } @lists
```

Comment: Ah ha! so map is used for those purpose huh?
Thumbs up! I'm beginner of perl but it looks amazing language!!
Thanks.

Comment: @Yoon: `map` is wonderful for doing all kinds of list processing.

Answer (score 6):

```
my @numbers = (22, 10, 5, 2);

# Create a new list, as in David Dorward's answer.
my @halves = map { $_ / 2 } @numbers;

# Or modify the original list directly.
$_ /= 2 for @numbers;
```